# Finding the minimum value of $\frac{\mu\cos\theta}{\cos\theta + \mu\sin\theta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

This is a part of a physics problem I was solving. 
I was supposed to find the minimum value of $\dfrac{\mu\cos\theta}{\cos \theta +\mu\sin \theta}$ where $\mu= 0.2$

The solution given used calculus to determine the minimum value (by finding the first derivative). However, being a pre-calculus student, I wonder if there's a way to solve this problem without using derivatives. I tried using $AM/GM$ but there's a $\mu$ causing trouble.

Any method to solve this without calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Originally Answered: Find min-max of $\cos{\theta + \mu\sin{\theta}}$

The general form of the answer is

$$
-\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leq a\cos{\theta} + b\sin{\theta} \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$

Look for the non calculus solution below.

### Does this help?

[This article gives a nice, non calculus proof.](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/cstar050/mat1318a/nov18.pdf)

### The Edited Question (totally different): Find min-max of $\frac{\mu\cos{\theta}}{\cos{\theta + \mu\sin{\theta}}}$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos{\theta}$ we get,

$$
\frac{\mu}{1+\mu\tan{\theta}}
$$

### **Note that the numerator is constant while the denominator has only one variable $\tan{\theta}$ term.**

### Finding a min-max value for the function is futile, because [as this graph shows](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wxrjmlwoo2), the function can achieve any real value and is not bounded.

Comment: (Thanks) I know the proof already (so no need for that :)). This didn't click immediately to me therfore I couldn't apply it.

Comment: Is it possible to find $\theta$ using this? I need $\theta$ in the later part of the problem.

Comment: @Abcd I don't understand, if  you know the value of \theta then the expression is constant

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @Abcd Better post the full question only:)

Comment: @Abcd And if you _really_ are happy with my solution, the best way to say thanks! on this website is to accept my answer.

Comment: But $\tan\theta's$ maximum value is infinity

Comment: @Abcd I said that better to post the full question rather than posting half of it and then changing it completely again. Have you understood my solution? Yes you are right about tan

Comment: So I cannot proceed from where you have left

Comment: Did you get it now @Abcd ?

Comment: Yes @DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb